# Load the document into the iframe jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to access the currently loaded document of an iframe and link that document to another iframe, for this I tried:

```
   $("#if1").attr("src", $("#if2").attr("src"));
```

But this loads the document again. I want to access the document already loaded in `#if1`. How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by 'link that document with another iframe'? And @Derek, how did you bypass the min 15 chars limit?

Comment: Are these iframes under the same domain?

Comment: yes they are under the same domain

Comment: i tried that, but it didn't work...don't know why? But will try that again. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#if1").attr("src", $("#if2").attr("src"));
```

*But this loads the document again.*

Err, yeah, that's what you are doing: you are setting `if1`'s src to `if2`'s src. That's why it reloads the iFrame... If you exchange if1 and if2 in your code it might do what you're trying to do -- if I managed to understand you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this running demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aymansafadi/BanTV/5/show/

The key part you might be interested is:

```
$('#swap').on('click', function() {
    var iframe1 = $('#if1')[0].contentWindow.location.href;
    var iframe2 = $('#if2')[0].contentWindow.location.href;

    $('#if1')[0].contentWindow.location.href = iframe2;
    $('#if2')[0].contentWindow.location.href = iframe1;
});
```

> **NOTE:** This, and anything else you you try, will only work if both iframes are under the same domain as the parent window.

---

You can also use `.src('attr')` to **set** the URL, but not *get* the current URL.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aymansafadi/BanTV/7/show/

```
$('#swap').on('click', function() {
    var iframe1 = $('#if1')[0].contentWindow.location.href;
    var iframe2 = $('#if2')[0].contentWindow.location.href;

    $('#if1').attr('src', iframe2);
    $('#if2').attr('src', iframe1);
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply but can u tell me pls whats the difference b/w `  $("#if1").attr("src", $("#if2").attr("src"));` and in ur answer

Comment: `.attr('src')` is nothing more that the value of the `src` attribute. While the URL inside the iframe may change, the value of the `src` attribute will not. In other words, you can use the `src` attribute to set the location of the iframe, but not get the current location. See other demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aymansafadi/BanTV/7/show/